# How Singleton Pattern works in a web scope?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, web-applications, singleton

I know how the Singleton pattern works, but I have doubt how it works in a web scope. Is not naturally by request?

A request is made and the singleton is instantiated and the request has ended. The singleton was destroyed? If yes, why some people doing to let singleton in request scope explicitly? If no, what happens? The singleton remains in the memory and a new one is created for each request?

**Update:**

When I say "why some people doing to let singleton in request scope explicitly", is for example using Ninject I have to do it:

```
Bind<ISession>().To(SessionSingleton.Instance).InRequestScope();
```

**Update 2:**

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

**Update 3:**

My `DbContext` is Singleton? I think No, my `DbContextFactory` is singleton, BUT my `DbContext` in this case will be destroyed when the request ended?

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    #region Fields

    private static volatile DbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();
    public DbContext Context;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public static DbContextFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbContextFactory == null)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_dbContextFactory == null)
                        _dbContextFactory = new DbContextFactory();
                }
            }
            return _dbContextFactory;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public DbContext GetOrCreateContext()
    {
        if (this.Context == null)
            this.Context = new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnectionString"]);

        return Context;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: In case you havn't been told already, almost all singletons are evil.

Comment: What language/platform/framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the context of a web app there are objects with global scope. One of them is System.Web.HttpApplication which is created by the framework. Also static instances have global scope. These global objects lifetime is tied to the lifetime of your Application ( not of the web request). The framework might stop and start your application ( think app pool recycling ).

In the context of a web app singletons also have global scope, so they are tied to the lifetime of the application and will not be destroyed at the end of each request. They might be destroyed and recreated when the web app is restarted, but that should not meter to your app.

Also to complete what others have said, it's true that singletons are usually evil and that you should think twice before designing something as a singleton, except when they are exactly what you need. Some examples where you might want to ensure you only have one instance are logging, caching, NHibernate's session factory  and other cross-cutting infrastructure components, and also models for resources that exist as only one instance.

Comment: @lulian see my update please... my singleton class have a global scope because of static keyword?

Comment: Yes, using static makes the instance field have global scope. BUT your implementation has a few problems - remember all threads for all concurrent requests will access the same instance of your singleton. I will not go into details - use Google for singleton implementations if you need it. At least change it to private static Singleton instance = new Singleton(); and in the Instance property just return Singleton.instance. Also remember that all public methods on the Singleton class MUST be thread safe. And if you have the time consider not using a singleton :)

Comment: Your DbContextFactory is indeed a singleton. But the way you create the DbContext is wrong. First of all only one DbContext is ever created, on the first call to GetOrCreateContext. As I said in the last comment all the methods in your singleton MUSt be thread safe. The GetOrCreateContext method IS NOT thread safe. Also you assume that the DbContext field will be destroyed at the end of the request which is wrong. There is nothing destroying the context or setting it null at the end of the request.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is a per-request db context then a singleton does not fit. You can either use a IOC container that supports per web request object lifetime or create a new context on HttpApplication.BeginRequest event, store it in HttpContext.Current.Items and dispose it on EndRequest event. Google should have more details on per request linq2sql context

Comment: but look at my DbContext object, it is not static, it is not have a global scope, the Garbage Collector destroyed at end of your use, I'm wrong? I don't understand what happens...

Comment: Your singleton which has global scope has a member of type DbContext. The member has the scope of the containing class. Unless explicitly  created/destroyed members of a singleton class also have singleton scope. I recommend you pause and re-think the hole situation, maybe read some other examples, i'm sure it will become clear :)

Answer (score 0):

As Raynos said: Singletons **are** evil.

But answering your question, the singleton doesn't get instatiated or destroyed for each request, but it remains in memory and is shared between all requests regarless of when the request is made.

I don't fully understand whay you mean by *why some people doing to let singleton in request scope explicitly?*. Are you talking about a spefic framework? (for some reason I have the feeling you're talking about Spring). Can you give an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: See update please. But when my request end all objects are destroyed by Garbage Collector in .Net?